# Passing multiple arguments to a thread from a structure

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, arguments

I'm having problems passing the arguments, using a structure containing another structure

i know there's something wrong with the way i'm using the structures but i just cant see where...

Thanks!

this is my struct

```
typedef struct {
IMAGE *imagenfte;
IMAGE *imagendst;
}thread_data;

//thread_data *data = (thread_data *) malloc(sizeof(thread_data));
```

this is the other structure

```
 typedef struct {
    HEADER header;
    INFOHEADER infoheader;
    PIXEL *pixel;
    } IMAGE;

IMAGE imagenfte,imagendst;
```

this is my thread function

```
void *processBMP2(void *argumentos) 
{
thread_data *my_data;
my_data =  (thread_data *) (argumentos);
IMAGE *imagefte, *imagedst;
imagefte =  my_data->imagenfte;
imagedst = my_data->imagendst;
free(my_data);
int i,j;
int count=0;
PIXEL *pfte,*pdst;
PIXEL *v0,*v1,*v2,*v3,*v4,*v5,*v6,*v7;
int imageRows,imageCols;
memcpy(imagedst,imagefte,sizeof(IMAGE)-sizeof(PIXEL *));
imageRows = imagefte->infoheader.rows;
imageCols = imagefte->infoheader.cols;
imagedst->pixel=(PIXEL *)malloc(sizeof(PIXEL)*imageRows*imageCols);
...
```

and this is the way i`m creating the thread and passing de arguments

```
     pthread_t hilo;

thread_data *my_data = (thread_data *) malloc(sizeof(thread_data));

my_data->imagenfte = &imagenfte;
my_data->imagendst = &imagendst;

pthread_create(&hilo,NULL, processBMP2, my_data);

//processBMP(&imagenfte,&imagendst);
```

Comment: How are the two `IMAGE` objects allocated? If they are on the stack instead of the heap, then that may be your issue. Make sure they will be valid for the lifetime of the thread.

Comment: @Evan: Good point, I missed that possibility...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing multiple arguments to a thread in C (pthread_create)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524433/passing-multiple-arguments-to-a-thread-in-c-pthread-create)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is exactly right. The new thread needs to be the one responsible for freeing the memory because the parent thread cannot know when the new thread is done accessing it.

Comment: This depends on whether the thread is joinable... if it is, then the parent thread can free the memory after joining the terminated thread.

Comment: Well yes, there are lots of ways you could synchronize making the parent responsible for freeing it. Even with a detached thread, if the structure contains synchronization objects to communicate back to the parent, the parent could know when it's legal to free it. But for one-way argument-passing structures like OP is using, having the new thread free it is probably the cleanest.